# SQL JOIN for three tables

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

I have Three tables

**tbl_Service**

```
1)sId
2)Name
```

**tbl_quatItem**

```
1)iId
2)quat_ID
3)ser_Id
```

**tbl_quat**

```
1)qId
2)date
3)Name
```

I've tried the following statement

```
select s.*, q.* 
from tbl_service s, tbl_quatItem q 
where q.quatID = 1001 
and s.sId not in q.qutID
```

Now I want to fetch data from `tbl_Service` which are not in `tbl_quatItem` and `quat_Id = qID`

Comment: Good luck then. Please come back if you get stuck and show us where.

Comment: I tried joins but it not works

Comment: Can you show us what you have done by editing the original question. Also, how are these tables linked?

Comment: I still don't understand your request, can you be more specific ?

Comment: I have three tables 
tbl_quat 
1)qId primary Key 
2)name

tbl_service
1)SID primary KEY
2)Name

tbl_quatItem
1)iTd primay ker
2)qID foreign key of tbl_quat
3)sID foreign key of tbl_service

now i want to fetch data from tbl_service where qID = 1001 and sID not in tbl_quatItem

Comment: That's fine, but can you show us what you have attempted to do so far? It's difficult to explain where you are going wrong without seeing what you are actually trying to do!

Comment: select s.*, q.* from tbl_service s, tbl_quatItem q where q.quatID = 1001 and s.sId not in q.qutID

Comment: OK, I've updated the question - what database are you actually using? You've tagged it as MySQL and Oracle.

Comment: select * from tbl_service where Id not in  (select serID from quat_item where quatId =1002)

Comment: Then how about @Aun 's answer? and what is subservice? please include it in your post as well, in an organized way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select * from tbl_Service where sId not in  (select ser_Id from tbl_quat_ID where quat_Id != <qID>)
```

i hope qID is passed from application side.. you just need to append the string to pass proper value there

Comment: meaning the query string will be like 
   String query = "select * from tbl_Service where sId not in  (select ser_Id from tbl_quat_ID where quat_Id != " + qID + ")";